# Is there a way to express type guard inside object?

Tags: typescript

I want to use type guard with additional information like below.

```
type Something = string | number;

const isSomething = (anything: unknown): {
    result: anything is Something,
    additionalInfo: any
} => {
    ...
}

...

const afterTypeGuard = isSomething(thing);
if (afterTypeGuard.result === true) {
    return {
        afterTypeGuard.additionalInfo,
        length: thing.length,
    }
} else {
    return (thing + 32) * 3;
}

...
```

But I couldn't set return type `result: anything is Something` instead of `result: boolean`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try using *typeof*?

Comment: No, this is not possible; there are feature requests at [ms/TS#31376](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31376) and [ms/TS#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is [no, you can't enhance the return type of a custom type guard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71278708/21146235), although as jcalz noted there is a relevant [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650).

There are a couple of approaches described in that [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71278708/21146235) – "extract the `additionalInfo` separately", or "assign the `additionalInfo` as a side-effect of the type guard" – but maybe closer to what you have described is to include the original value as part of the result, with a narrowed type. In a simple formulation this could be:

```js
type GuardResult<T> = {
    result: true;
    value: T;
    additionalInfo: any;
} | { result: false }

const isString = (anything: unknown): GuardResult<string> =>
    typeof anything === "string"
        ?    { result: true, value: anything, additionalInfo: "foo" }
        :    { result: false }

function processThing(thing: unknown) {
    const stringGuard = isString(thing);
    if (stringGuard.result) {
        // Note: although `stringGuard.value === thing`,
        // `stringGuard.value is string` but `thing is unknown`
        return {
            additionalInfo: stringGuard.additionalInfo,
            length: stringGuard.value.length,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp0Ggm)

With a little extra work, `GuardResult` can be extended to narrow the type for the complementary type (i.e. when `result` is false):

```
type GuardResult<V, T> = {
    result: true;
    value: T;
    additionalInfo: any;
} | {
    result: false;
    value: Exclude<V, T>;
}

const isString = <V>(anything: V): GuardResult<V, string> => (
    (typeof anything === "string")
        ?   { result: true,  value: anything, additionalInfo: "foo" }
        :   { result: false, value: anything as Exclude<V, string> }
);

function processThing(thing: Something) {
    const stringGuard = isString(thing);
    if (stringGuard.result) {  // stringGuard.value is string
        return {
            additionalInfo: stringGuard.additionalInfo,
            length: stringGuard.value.length,
        }
    } else {  // stringGuard.value is number
        return (stringGuard.value + 32) * 3;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w22obw) / [Expanded playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqYoJm)

Along similar lines but with a little bit of type abuse you could do something along the lines of the `Either` pattern from functional programming – have your guard-like function return a pair broadly denoting "success" and "failure", e.g. `[inputValue, undefined]` if `inputValue` is of the guarded type, and `[undefined, inputValue]` otherwise, with appropriate type narrowing on the two cases:

```js
function guard<V, T>(value: unknown): [T, undefined] | [undefined, Exclude<V, T>] { ... }
```

This can get a little messy (see [this example](https://tsplay.dev/wXvLQm) for a quick and dirty implementation) because the `undefined` values leak out, but the return value does destructure in quite a pleasing way:

```js
    const [stringValue, notStringValue, additionalInfo] = isString(thing);
    if (stringValue) {
        // thing === stringValue
        alert(stringValue + " is a string");
    } else {
        // thing === notStringValue
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using type alias with a conditional statement?

```
type Something = string | number;

type SomethingGuard<T> = {
    result: T extends Something ? true : false,
    additionalInfo: any
};

const isSomething = (anything: unknown): SomethingGuard<typeof anything> => {
    // type guard logic here
    return {
        result: typeof anything === "string" || typeof anything === "number",
        additionalInfo: "additional information"
    };
}

const thing: unknown = "hello";
const afterTypeGuard = isSomething(thing);
if (afterTypeGuard.result === true) {
    return {
        additionalInfo: afterTypeGuard.additionalInfo,
        length: (thing as string).length,
    }
} else {
    return (thing as number + 32) * 3;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if this worked but [unfortunately it doesn't compile](https://tsplay.dev/WKPZpw). The declaration `(anything: unknown) => SomethingGuard<typeof anything>` means that `typeof anything` will always be `unknown`, and `unknown extends Something` will always be false. You can shift the errors around a bit by introducing a generic parameter but then the explicit type coercions `(thing as string)` or `(thing as number)` end up doing the heavy lifting anyway.